# Fetching data from SQL Server 2005 using c#

Tags: c#, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I would like to retrieve a particular column from a table when the values from two other columns are equal. My code is as follows. The four columns are `id,destination,source,price`.

I want to display the price when the destination and source are equal.

Could you please help me?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=.;initial catalog=loki;integrated security=true");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select  price from metro where source='" + textBox1.Text + "' and destination='" + textBox2.Text + "'", con);
        da.Fill(dt);
        for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            textBox3.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by why you include textBox1 and 2. If you want to test whether source and destination are equal, I think the query should be: SELECT price FROM metro WHERE source=destination

Comment: Please use parameterized queries (or even better, [stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190782(v=sql.90))).  Using string concatenation to build SQL commands is just asking for a [SQL injection attack](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: david hyogo....source and destination are two diifernt inputs.....thats why i have to take different.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you are after this ....

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=.;initial catalog=loki;integrated security=true"))
        {
            string query = "select  price from metro where source= @Source and destination = @Destination";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Destination", textBox2.Text);

                con.Open();
                object o  = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if(o != null && o != DBNull.Value)
                {
                   string price = (string) o; //please cast the return type as required
                   textBox3.Text = price;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thier is error that specified cast is not valid "int price = (Int32) cmd.ExecuteScalar();"

Comment: I gave it as example if your return type is decimal then please cast it to decimal

Comment: Please see update code I have taken care of cmd.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: this one string price = (string) o;

Comment: okay okay i get it but error still their.....cannot completely convert type int to string

Comment: o is an object that was returned by ExecuteScalar see link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Comment: please taking this thread as iwill be needing more help in this project.....thanks a lot........